# LaTeX: Numbering only last line of multi-line equation in \align

Tags: latex

I want to number and make a reference to just the last line of a multi-line equation in `\align`. Here is an example:

```
\begin{align}
z_1^2 &= \left( 2 e^{i \frac{\pi}{3}} \right) \left( 2 e^{i \frac{\pi}{3}} \right)\\
&= 4 e^{i \frac{2 \pi}{3}}
\end{align}
```

I only want to number the `&= 4 e^{i \frac{2 \pi}{3}}` part, rather than both lines of the `\align`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

From the amsmath documentatiom ([amsldoc.pdf](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf)):

> You can suppress the number on any
>   particular line by putting \notag 
>   before the \\;

So your equation should look like this (some bits removed from your equation to make it shorter):

```
\begin{align}
z_1^2 &= \left( ... \right) \left( ... \right)\notag\\
&= 4 e^{i \frac{2 \pi}{3}}
\end{align}
```

Comment: Conversely, if there are many lines, one could just add \tag as shown in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42726/align-but-show-one-equation-number-at-the-end.